# VBA SUMIF between a range of dates

Tags: vba, loops, date, declaration, sumifs

I have 24 columns with dollar amounts in them (H:AE). I have summed them into 3 categories, ATC(24 hours)in AG, On Peak (8-23) in AH, and Off Peak (1-7,24) in AI. In column AK, AL, and AM, I have summed the ATC, On Peak and Off Peak for all instances of a PNODENAME in column E. In column AT, the correct price band (from column AP) is chosen, however, if the date in column A is a weekend then it returns the ATC sum.

I'm stuck at the next part, in column AV there is a period of time that relates to the the time period to be summed for atc(around the clock), peak, or offpeak, based on date. For example DAY needs all offpeak prices for the month of DEC (as well as ATC for the weekends). To keep it interesting, some of the nodes need quarterly summing, like June through August. Of course to make it interesting this needs to loop. Thinking of putting the sum in row AX.

I'm wondering if I can declare a period of time? Any suggestions welcomed. This is what i have so far......

```
Sub LMPTest()

    'Looping Sum for ATC by row

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
       Range("AG" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H" & i & ":AE" & i))

    Next i

    'Looping Sum for ONPEAK by row

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("AH" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("O" & i & ":AD" & i))

    Next i

    'Looping Sum for OFFPEAK by row

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("AI" & i) = Val(Range("AG" & i).Value) - Val(Range("AH" & i).Value)

    Next i

    'Looping ATC Sumif Node Matches #### Needs to be from PJM Period

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("pjm_lmp_table").Range("AK" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF(pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!AG:AG)"

    Next i

    'Looping ONPEAK Sumif Node Matches #### Needs to be from PJM Period

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row
       Worksheets("pjm_lmp_table").Range("AL" & i).Formula ="=SUMIF(pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!AH:AH)"

    Next i

    'Looping OFFPEAK Sumif Node Matches #### Needs to be from PJM Period

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("pjm_lmp_table").Range("AM" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF(pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!AI:AI)"

    Next i

    'Looping Sumif Day of Week

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Weekday(Range("A" & i).Value) > 6 Or Weekday(Range("A" & i).Value) < 2 Then

    Range("AT" & i).Value = Range("AK" & i).Value

    ElseIf Range("AP" & i) = "ONPEAK" Then
                                    Range("AT" & i).Value = Range("AL" & i)

    ElseIf Range("AP" & i) = "OFFPEAK" Then
                                        Range("AT" & i).Value2 = Range("AM" & i)

    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqKdD.jpg)

[image: OP's screenshot]

Comment: The [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) formulas (e.g. `=SUMIF(pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!E:E, pjm_lmp_table!AG:AG)`) do not look right. Are all of these on the **pjm_lmp_table** worksheet? Should that be `=SUMIF(E:E, E2, AG:AG)`?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, all are on pjm_lmp_table worksheet. It was the only way I could get the PNODENAME to sum. Of note, it will eventually check NODENAME on another sheet, I didn't want to make it too complicated, I'm really new to VBA.

Comment: Well, it goes without saying that I am not typing out that sample data. If you were going to write a formula into AM2, what would it be? What about AK2? What happened to AL2?

Comment: Haha, yeah, I only put the screenshot up for reference. There are a lot of rows hidden so I could get the important ones in the screenshot.I think I need some code prior to the last bit of code that relates to the weekday(range("A" & i).Value - something like SUMIF(Range("A" & i).value = "December" Else next i .... I'm sure this isn't right. AK, AL, AM might be redundant. AT is the important one but it needs to sum only the period in AV.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a complete answer, I want to point you in the right direction to both speed up the process by removing the loops and simply matters so that you can make more adjustments yourself.

```
Sub LMPTest()
    Dim lr As Long

    With Worksheets("pjm_lmp_table")   '<~~ always specify the worksheet!
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

        'Looping Sum for ATC by row
        .Range("AG2:AG" & lr).Formula = "=SUM(H2:AE2)"
        .Range("AH2:AH" & lr).Formula = "=SUM(O2:AD2)"
        'Looping Sum for OFFPEAK by row
        .Range("AI2:AI" & lr) = "=AG2-AH2"
        'Looping ATC Sumif Node Matches #### Needs to be from PJM Period
        .Range("AK2:AK" & lr).Formula = "=SUMIF(E:E, E2, AG:AG)"

        'revert formula to result values
        .Range("AG2:AK" & lr) = .Range("AG2:AL" & lr).Value2

        'Looping OFFPEAK Sumif Node Matches #### Needs to be from PJM Period
        .Range("AM2:AM" & lr).Formula = "=SUMIFS(AI:AI, E:E, E2, AP:AP, AM$1)"
        'revert formula to result values
        .Range("AM2:AM" & lr) = .Range("AM2:AM" & lr).Value2

        'Looping Sumif Day of Week
        .Range("AT2:AT" & lr).Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)={7, 1}), AK2, " & _
                                         "IF(AP2=""ONPEAK"", AL2, " & _
                                         "IF(AP2=""OFFPEAK"", AM2, """")"
        'revert formula to result values
        .Range("AT2:AT" & lr) = .Range("AT2:AT" & lr).Value2

    End With

End Sub
```

All of the formulas inserted into the full columns of ranges are the formulas that you would type into the second row of that column. This is the same as putting the formula into the second row and then filling down. The formulas are removed leaving their result values afterwards. The [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) because the nature of these values is strictly numeric and the .Value2 is the rawest value property there is.

**tl;dr:** In short, if you can design a working formula for the second row then this method will benefit your development.